# set execution time of a selector method

Tags: objective-c, ios7

Is there any way to set execution time for any Selector Method . Although i know we can call any method after some delay but my requirement is to fire a method at a particular instance of a time .

Answer (score 0):

`NSTimer` has `initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` which takes a fire date, allowing you to specify an exact moment in time when the timer should fire its selector.

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Interval is an `NSTimeInteral`, which is in seconds, not milliseconds. This parameter is used if you decide that the timer should repeat (it species what interval the repeats should occur). Using this method the timer will not fire until the exact date that you specify, and will then continue to fire at each invert specified (if repasts is set to YES).

Comment: what if i have to fire that method at midnight daily without user interaction ?

Comment: NSTimer will only fire while your app is in the foreground. Mert's suggestion of scheduling a local notification is the right direction, but nothing will happen unless a user acts on that notification. You need to describe your requirement in a lot more detail, or else we're just shooting in the dark.

Comment: @Jasarein well my requirement is to set a local notification at mid night daily without the user interaction . But as you say it is quite not possible to schedule it without user interaction , so what should be the other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [UILocalNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
In order to run that particular method, your app must be at foreground.

Comment: This is what my requirement is , i want to schedule a local notification at midnight all by itself without opening app .

Comment: It is simply impossible :( There is very little you can do while your app is at background.

Comment: @SauravMac you should have been more specific. Your question mentioned nothing about wanting to perform actions while the app was in the background, or utilising any kind of notifications. It was a stroke of luck that Mert Buran suggested `UILocalNotification` and happened to find the solution your your issue.

Comment: Let's just call it empathy, instead of luck :)

Comment: @jasarien Okay sir , but still i haven't found any solution to my problem  :(

Comment: Edit your question and include as much detail about your requirement as you can. Explain what you want to happen and what you've already tried.

Comment: You should mention that you want to do some background operations, but before that it'd be better you google them.